# Finding a font used on old topographic maps

Tags: fonts, font-identification

On the first generation of Romanian topographic maps (before 1900), there was a certain font used for labeling natural features.

It looks like this:

[image: part of an old Romanian map symbol atlas]

I managed to find a reference from 1907 for the fonts used in those maps, and the one that I'm interested in was called by Romanian cartographers *Batard*, which I know is an old French script.

I want to replicate the style of those maps and I'm interested in knowing if there is any font similar to this, because all the *batard* examples I have seen are very different from what I'm looking for. I also tried using the usual online identification services, but with no success.

Comment: It’s nowhere near a perfect match, but it’s also not wholly dissimilar to [Ronde Script](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/grouptype/ronde-script/) (and its bedfellows, French Script and Typo Upright).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried, but it is impossible to find something similar. Some time ago I use to make calligraphy, and this was one of the most recurrent letters and not the hardest to make with a square pen.

It's **Gothic Round Bastard Straight**.
Search in Google Images with the text in Spanish: Gótica bastarda redonda recta.

The name of Bastard has several origins, my preference is the most practical:

**Bastard**: the stroke thickness or modulation is due to the pen inclination. In classical calligraphy, the modulation is produced by the pressure of the pen on the paper. The higher the pressure, the greater the opening of the pen blades and the ink flow is higher.

[image: pen 01]

**Round**: because this is how the joints of the strokes are, different than the square ones:

[image: square]

**Straight**: actually this is not a variant, it is only the difference with the *slanted* or *italics*.

As calligraphy is not very difficult to make, it's just a matter of skill and practice.

It is possible to achieve a vector emulation with a calligraphic brush in **Illustrator**:

[image: Pen]

[image: letter]

Of course drawing all the letters with a vector brush is a nightmare. But many strokes are repeated or very similar. Starting with a square calligraphy which is simpler, the round is easy to get:

[image: strokes]

With some guides, repeating strokes, regulating distances ...

[image: base]

...someone can make a font:

[image: font]

I know it's not a solution, but maybe an idea, or at list some information.

Comment: You say this isn't a solution, but it really is an excellent solution.  If the font has never been digitised, recreating it by hand calligraphy may be the only realistic option. I was thinking of answering similarly, but you've beat me to it!!

Comment: Thank you for spending so much time of your time to answer. It is indeed an excellent solution.